# What's the "Red Eye" drug and what does it do?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In Cowboy Bebop, it's noted that a red thread-like substance in a glass vial called "Red Eye" or "Red Dye" (I'm not sure which) is an illegal substance that can cause some sort of heightened state.

What is it? What does it do? and why is it used in the story?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's basically a stimulant that enhances physical ability (among other things).

> Bloody Eye (aka Red Eye) is a drug developed by an illegal syndicate of which Asimov Solensan was a member. This drug is the main driving force behind the story of Session 1, and is also mentioned and seen to varying degrees throughout the series. Vicious is also known to deal in Bloody Eye, and it is suspected he uses it as well.

And

> Bloody Eye is similar to a very powerful steroid and stimulant combined into one. It makes the user extremely hyper and aware. They perceive time at a very rapid rate, causing everything around them to appear to move in slow motion. The user gains significant physical strength. It also appears that the user becomes agitated and angry, however Asimov Solensan is the only person ever seen taking Bloody Eye so this could be due more to his personality and predicament than the drug. A person on Bloody Eye is known to be quite a force to be reckoned with; Asimov took down numerous men without any weapons while on Bloody Eye, making him seemingly impossible to capture.

Full details can be found on the [Cowboy Bebop wiki](https://cowboybebop.fandom.com/wiki/Bloody_Eye).

Comment: So that's what its called... I thought it was called "Red Eye" thanks!

Comment: I'm betting the Red Eye was derived during the translation or the dubbing.

Comment: Yea, the English version...

Comment: Probably didn't want to scare kids with a word like "Bloody"

Comment: Lol... Just curious. I kinda like "Red Eye".

Comment: So, all the best and worst features of PCP, crystal meth, crack and anabolic steroids. And it's as addictive as nicotine or heroin.